# Disable scrolling on `<input type=number>` in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mousewheel

This question was asked before but provided solution is just for `jQuery`, as I'm facing same problem in ReactJs.

Is it possible to disable the scroll wheel changing the number in an input number field? I removed spinner arrows using CSS but mouse wheel still working and messing the functionality.

I want input type `number` because it gives numeric keyboard on mobile/touch devices.

Comment: Did you tried doing e.preventDefault() for that field ?

Comment: yes I've tried, even I tried to write code in public/index.html to remove mousewheel event in javascript (outside of react), but it didn't work. may be I did some mistake

Comment: Check this , it is plain JS and HTML https://codepen.io/ahastudio/pen/eVovMv

Comment: I have tried this - <input type="number" className = "myClass" onWheel = {(e) => this.getWheel(e)}></input>

and inside the getWheel method - e.target.blur(); 

Kindly try this once.

Comment: @Asutosh this solution https://codepen.io/ahastudio/pen/eVovMv is for jQuery but not for ReactJs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, except I was working on desktop version only.
To blur the focus on the input as suggested in other answers works to stop the scrolling. But it wasn't what I wanted. I still want the user to be able to change the input with the keyboard.

So to disable scrolling on `<input type=number>` in React I added an `onFocus` property as follows:

```
<input
    //...some input properties...//
    type="number"
    onFocus={(e) => e.target.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) { e.preventDefault() }, { passive: false })}
/>
```

It worked fine for me. I hope it helps others.

Answer (score 61):

**Simplest answer:**

```
<input type="number" onWheel={(e) => e.target.blur()} />
```

`e` is short for `event`.

This also works:

```
<input type="number" onWheel={() => document.activeElement.blur()} />
```

Either of these can be used either in a **functional** or in a **class** component.

Comment: For TypeScript you will need to cast it to the `HTMLElement` type... `(e.target as HTMLElement).blur();`

Comment: Try `e.target instanceof HTMLElement` as a safe alternative in TypeScript. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5901#issuecomment-431649653

Answer (score 24):

You can blur the field on onWheel handler. Something like this

```
<input type='number' onWheel={ event => event.currentTarget.blur() } />
```

Comment: This solution solve the TS problem using  `<input type='number' onWheel={ event => event.target.blur() } />

Answer (score 3):

I solved this using a functional component that wraps the `input` element and adds an event listener for `"wheel"` and prevents default behavior. I find this preferable to using `blur()` which may have undesirable UX.

```js
// Simply a wrapper for <input type="number"/> that disables scrolling to increment

import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export const NumberInput = (props) => {
  const quantityInputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ignoreScroll = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    };
    quantityInputRef.current && quantityInputRef.current.addEventListener("wheel", ignoreScroll);
  }, [quantityInputRef]);

  return <input ref={quantityInputRef} type="number" {...props} />;
};
```

In production, I actually use this component to disable scroll-incrementing for the `<TextField>` component from material-ui instead of `<input>`. I've used the native input in my example because that's what the question was asking about.

Comment: In React 17.0.2 I see an error saying you can't preventDefault on a passive event listener

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is the best solution **if you only want a numeric keyboard** since there is a property that actually let you set whatever keyboard type you want, e.g. [`inputMode="numeric"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode)

Changing global events is not good practice and neither is blurring out of the field.

Answer (score 1):

In react version you should use ref. Take a look at the example below :

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";

class MyInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = createRef();
  }

  onWheel = () => {
    this.inputRef.current.blur();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        My input number :
        <input type="number" ref={this.inputRef} onWheel={this.onWheel} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyInput;
```

[codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-leaf-g1mgl?file=/src/MyInput.js:0-417)

Comment: Thanks @Sephyre for above code, This worked fine but due to blur() method it is not user friendly.
As I roll mouse wheel it looses focus and for input I have to click again in the input field to add a number.

Comment: Look at this fiddle, this experience is really nice and smooth, https://jsfiddle.net/x6o7dzuv/

Comment: Add this to onWheel function `setTimeout(() => this.inputRef.current.focus(), 100);`

Answer (score 1):

###### Prevent onWheel's event

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event)

[event blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event)

[example in react](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-estrela-oq2hfc)

```
const inputElem = useRef();

onWheel={e=> {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputElem.current.blur();
 } 
}
```

- in react code

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const inputElem = useRef();
  const handleOnWheel = (e) => {
    // if not use preventDefault, it is working 
    e.preventDefault();
    // The blur event fires when an element has lost focus. The event does not bubble, 
    inputElem.current.blur();
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input
          ref={inputElem}
          type="number"
          placeholder="type num"
          // prevent scroll on number input
          onWheel={handleOnWheel}
        />
        <button type="submit">send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does not work in Firefox, I can still change the number with the scroll wheel in the provided sandbox

Comment: it is working well on mine. mac firebox browser. are you using windows?

Comment: I am using Firefox 113.0.1 (64-bit) on Ubuntu

Comment: Tried Chromium 113.0.5672.126 too, it is also not working there

Comment: I've updated the codesandbox and answer as well, pls try and check it out. I hope it is working welllll. Thanks

Comment: Now it works, but the solution repeats [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63224812/4883195) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67157325/4883195), which both use blur to remove the focus from the input before the scroll happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove this scroll feature from all the number input fields of your project as whole or alternatively you could only import it into your component and this is the solution that worked for me.

First you create a custom hook like this one in your desired location in your project.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
const DisableNumInputScroll = () => {
   const handleWheel = (event) => {
     const { type } = event.target;
     if(type === 'number'){
       event.preventDefault();
     }
   }
   useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel, { passive: false });

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);
      };
    }, []);

   return null;
};

export default DisableNumInputScroll;
```

Basically this adds a wheel event listener to the document and when the event occurs, it is checked if target of that event element is of type number. If yes, it will stop the default behavior which is responsible for the scroll increasing the number in input tag.

You can use this custom hook in your main App.js file like so,

```
import DisableNumInputScroll from './DisableNumInputScroll';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <DisableNumInputScroll />
      {/* Rest of your application */}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use attribute onWheel like this:

```
onWheel={(e) => e.currentTarget.blur()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another very simple way of achieving this, if you don't care about the controls either, is by putting the step property to 0.

```
<input type="number" step={0} />
```

and use CSS to hide the controls:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp

Answer (score -3):

this can also be achieved using css.

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
{ 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```